# Generate automatically sql files with Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I want to automatically generate sql files with different queries that have date filter in their where clause. So far i have done this and works ok, but i get in trouble when i have table1 with some dates from 2019 till 2020 and also tables achieved by year like table1_2018, table1_2017,...
I want to check if i have table1 already archived and do in where only check for that year and also check table1 with the rest of the dates

```
from pathlib import Path

tables=["table1","table2","table1_2018","table1_2017","table2_2016"]
years=["2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2021"]
months=["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"]
for t in tables:
     for y in years:
           for m in months:
                full_path = f"exported/files/{t}/{y}"
                Path(full_path ).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
                sqlcode="select * from {t} where some condition..."
                filename= (f"{t}_{y}_{m}.sql")
                with open(os.path.join(full_path ,filename),"w") as writer:
                     writer.write(sqlcode)
```

Comment: What woult be the expected outcome?

Comment: For each table separated folder with the name of the table, subfolder will be year and in year generated sql where year will be in the filter

Comment: so you will have to create more complex code - with some `if/elif/else` and some lists/dicst to remeber already archived tables.

Comment: yes, but i am stuck right now. I need some idea or some pseudo code to start working

Comment: `if y in t` to check year in table name. `archived.append( [t,y,m] )` and `if [t,y,m] in archived:`